# Crontab Line Date

Tags: cron

I'm getting ready to launch a crontab, but since I'm new at it, wanted to check with someone if they could verify that what I'm doing is correct.

```
* 3 * * 5 /usr/local/bin/backup.bash
```

The above crontab line will run my backup bash file EVERY Friday at 3 a.m., is that correct? I need it to run every Friday, not just one Friday and then stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `00` (or `0`) to the minute(s) field, otherwise it will be run for each minute from 03:00 to 03:59 on every friday.

So, to run the job at 03:00 AM every friday:

```
00 03 * * 5 /usr/local/bin/backup.bash
```

Comment: You saved me there! See? That's why I'm glad I checked on Stack Exchange. Thank you.

Comment: @GTSJoe Glad i could help :)